# Is it correct and natural to say "hire someone into the sales department"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, phrase-choice, collocations

Could you tell me if it's correct and natural to say *hire someone into the sales department*? For example:

> Kate has been **hired into** the sales department for her ability to connect with people.

If it doesn't sound right, can I say it the following way?

> Kate has been **hired for a position in** the sales department for her ability to connect with people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hired into" is slightly unusual, although there's nothing ungrammatical about it. English often allows a choice of pronouns.

You normally talk about someone being "hired for" a job in general, or "hired as" a particular job or position. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/hire) has "hires someone for a job working a cash register" and "hiring him as his personal instructor".

An alternative might be:

> Kate has been hired for the sales department for her ability to connect with people.

"For" is repeated, which is the only problem, and not a big problem.

It's common to talk about someone "being transferred into a department", "getting promoted into a job", and similar things, so "into" isn't weird. You may like "hired into" because it emphasises that someone is joining a team, and teams are important in business.

Or you could certainly write it as:

> Kate has been hired for a position in the sales department for her ability to connect with people.

That is a bit longer though.

Comment: *Hired **in** the sales department,* works well.  Bob was just hired in the sales department.  If I worked in the marketing department and we just hired Bob, that is how I would tell my co-workers.

Comment: When you say, "English often allows a choice of ***pronouns***", do you mean "... a choice of ***prepositions***"? There are no pronouns in the example sentence.